# Is there any Ubuntu 14.04 theme to make it look like Windows 10?

Tags: 14.04, windows, themes

I used windows 10 in  virtual box for a few days and i fell in love with its beauty. Is there a ubuntu theme to make it look like windows 10?

Comment: Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Disagree that this is opinion based, the question is NOT `what is the best` it is `does one exist`

Comment: http://www.noobslab.com/2014/05/numix-theme-for-ubuntulinux-mintother.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Windows 10 GTK Theme, here you go :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install windos-10-themes
```

[image: windows 10 theme]

[image: windows 10 theme]

[image: windows 10 theme]

---

See [Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/09/do-you-like-windows-10-look-but-love.html) & [Gnome Look](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+10+Theme?content=171327) for more information.

Comment: Do you know why i love ubuntu??

Comment: I think I can guess =)

Comment: how did you get the bottom panel? @hg8

Comment: The screenshot are from [Nooblab](http://www.noobslab.com/2015/09/do-you-like-windows-10-look-but-love.html) but I guess it is the Cinnamon  panel...

Comment: You people all love Ubuntu here, but should I? I've downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and guess what? None of your themes are working. What i am doing wrong? I hate these "close" crosses placed in top-left of each window, I want them on top-right! Kidding, I just want windows-like theme.

Comment: How do you get windows 10 looking taskbar. Also how to move windows close/minimize/maximize buttons to the right corner?

Comment: @kernel_panic using photoshop probably :^)

Comment: It is obvious. Cinnemon :)

Comment: will it work in all account or only in one? ;)

Answer (score 14):

I would say, Numix is a good choice

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme
```

[image]

Comment: I use numix theme, it's very nice, just FYI, you can have a blue version too http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/?content=160634

Comment: I use numix too. But windows 10 theme  is reeaalllyyyy beautiful

Answer (score 9):

Here are a couple of themes I found,unfortunately I could not find a windows 10 theme but

[This one looks like win 8 desktop](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/windows-8-metro-gtk-theme),flat windows, blue colour etc...

Based on OP comments this theme is not quite the same as a windows 10 one

[image]

[This one is more windows seven than eight](http://www.itworld.com/article/2698410/make-ubuntu-14-04-look-like-windows-7-or-windows-8.html), but the description on the page implies that it install a whole pack of windows based themes and icons, so you might find something there.

[image]

You can also look at Gnome look, there are three or four win 8 themes [in this search result.](http://gnome-look.org/content/search.php?xsortmode=new&search=1&type=167&user=&text=windows&sort=0&scorefilter=0&license=99&page=0)

Comment: windows 10 theme and 8 theme are very much different on close observation

Comment: I looked really hard, I just don't think it exists, this question has been viewed 1075 times today and no has presented one, so, you never know your look one of those 1075 people might just make one.

Comment: This might be the closest you can get at the moment. W10 is still pretty new and it will take some time for someone to make a W10 theme.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a nice Windows 10 theme by using a few individual packages.

[image]

[image]

GTK3 metacity theme: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+8+theme+By+Kunal?content=165937

Orion GTK3 theme: http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Orion-GTK3-Theme-281431756

Windows 8 icons: http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Windows+8+Icons+Theme?content=167957

And the wallpapers: http://www.windows8core.com/download-the-all-new-desktop-hd-wallpapers-from-windows-10-consumer-preview-build-9901/

You will have difficulty finding Windows 10 themes due to it being such a short time since release, but the above should do quite nicely for the present.

Comment: thats windowse 8....