# Why Gnome apps look weird

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, themes

I want to make my lubuntu look like Windows 8.1/10 (just for fun). I've installed WinAte icon set and it's window border theme. Since there was no widget them available in the pack I've installed "One more flat" for the widgets. It works perfect for many programs but all Gnome apps look like that:

[image: Software updates PL]

These dashed frames are almost everywhere. How do I fix that ?

Comment: Is the problem that it's in a different language or the dotted lines?

Comment: It's about lines. Language is correct.

Comment: Try this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/656405/367165

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about [this theme](https://github.com/nhermosilla14/WinAte), it seems that it was last updated 2 years ago.
In that time frame, much has changed in the way GTK3 draws it's themes. These dashed lines seem to be a side effect of out-of-date CSS.

The bad news is - the theme seems to be out of date, and will not render correctly in recent GTK.

The good news is, you can look at how other themes have handled this ([example with vertex theme](https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-theme)) and try to fix it yourself. You can find the reference guide [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkStyleContext.html).
You just need to handle the GTK3 related stuff, which should not be that much code.
I know it's probably not the answer you were looking for, but AFAIK it's the only change you have to get it to work correctly.

The same is valid if the problem is in the [One more flat](http://box-look.org/content/show.php?content=173888) theme.

Good luck trying to modernize the theme. I wouldn't say it's the easiest task in the world, but it shouldn't be the toughest one either. Especially if you are already familiar with GTK theme file locations. Bonus points if you are already familiar with CSS.

Comment: I think I will try to modernize them, so I could learn more about this matter. This answer gave me some idea of what is going on here but I will not accept it, for now, since maybe someone can point the problem directly.

Comment: Fair enough. If sombody has a better solution I'd be interested in it too.

Comment: Success! I've installed gnome-tweak-tool which conveniently displays all CSS related problems on startup. The problem was weird, because these frames were explicitly enabled in `gtk3/gtk-common.css`. Why? Who knows... But after commenting out all `outline-*` properties in the main block, everything looks as expected now.

Comment: Cool! Have you considered opening a pull request for the original theme? _-)

Comment: I am not really familiar with developing open source software and I can't find `One more flat` theme on GitHub. So I think I will leave it as it is.

Comment: Good point. I thought the problem was with `WinAte`. I couldn't find  public repository for `One more flat` either. Guess it's staying as it is.