# Please guide about ubuntu (newbie)

Tags: virtualbox, themes

i am new to ubuntu and have not yet installed it. I am a windows user and have no previous knowledge of ubuntu. I have just once installed ubuntu in virtual machine to see the OS. But right now i am quite frustrated by windows experience especially with win 10. I am seriously thinking to switch over to ubuntu but i need some guidelines.

1. I have always been a windows user. Though i am quite advanced user but not a very techy person. I am just scared if i install ubuntu on my main laptop as a normal OS for everyday use, what about the drivers. My laptop website doesn't give drivers for else than win 7 and onwards. I can't even install XP which was the best OS so far, even better than 7, this you would agree i know. But 7 also made a mark in the list of steady and rock solid OS.
2. I am using different software and i have their .exe files kept. I know nothing about terminal use and i often panic using cmd in windows, thinking something might go terribly wrong. I feel the terminal is same as cmd in windows. Once i tried the ubuntu in virtual machine just to see how it works, and i had a lot of trouble installing software via terminal because of no knowledge. I was reading forums and doing the things. The only peace of mind i had was, it was being done inside a virtual machine. So, if something went wrong, it is ok.
3. The familiarity with desktop, and other folders, knowing that if you are going to reinstall the OS due to problems, then there are pet folders which has your data in it (downloads, documents etc). How does linux store data in it.
4. I am a theme guy with windows. I cannot use the OS in its native form, it bores me soon. I like themes, icons sets etc. Is it possible in ubuntu?

and final question. What about peripherals. If i am using ubuntu, then the usb sticks would work normal? i mean if i transfer data to flash disk and give it to a friend who is using windows, will he be able to see files. What about using an external screen or projector for movies. My laptop HDMI port does it all.

Comment: You might be better to write individual questions with a single focus. Broader questions will often be closed on Ask Ubuntu....

Answer (score 3):

Imagine if you are shifting your home to a new one. What are the problems would you come across in the first week?  You would struggle to find out the right switch for your bathroom light. Things wouldn't be in the same place as before. Every morning you get up, it would take you a second to realize where you are.  But after a week, you get adjusted to it. You start loving your new home. *Similar* situation arises when you switch from windows to Ubuntu.

Here are some advantages and Disadvantages of switching from Windows to Linux :

Advantages :

- Its **free**. unlike windows,  Ubuntu won't charge you for using it. You can customize how ever you want it.
- ***Most*** of the **drivers are shipped with the kernel**. If not, you can easily find many guides on the web on installing them.
- **Open source alternatives:**  For most of the proprietary software you use on windows, you can find free open-source alternatives for them. Like Photoshop --> GIMP, MS-Office --> Libre

  If you are not happy with alternatives, don't worry, many proprietary software are available for Linux too. And you can even run your windows software on Linux with the help of emulators like WINE.
- **Ubuntu Community and Documentation** : This is the best part. In Linux, you can find many fourms and Q&A sites. You won't feel alone. ***Anything*** you find difficult , you are always welcome to ask for help here.

  Coming to the Documentation, I have no words. ***`man`*** is everything. You will find detailed information about each and every thing you use on Linux.
- **Cooler themes , and more opportunity for customization**

  Unlike windows, Here you have choice to install and use any Desktop environment. You can find so many themes. Have a look here : http://www.noobslab.com/p/themes-icons.html .

  Guess what ? you can even make it look like windows-10 : [Really ? click here](https://askubuntu.com/q/656399/497359)
- **Better security** : You might already know this, there is no need of any anti-virus software for Linux (there are some, if you need) . On linux - No virus, no disease nothing. So you saved some bucks and your data and your privacy.

Disadvantages :

*hm... wait a second, I am thinking of some ...*

- Though it is not usually required to use command line for a casual user, It is very much recommended to know the basics. So it would take you some time to get used to it.
- **Gaming support** : though there are many many cool games for linux, You will still find Linux lacking support for ***high end games***. You can use [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/) on Linux, but native gaming.. not much.
- Your friends  use windows ? or .. are you a student ?

  As a student, I some time find it difficult to set up Windows software or find alternatives to those Windows software they use in my College. And If your friends use Windows, you might want to consider dual booting rather than switching to Linux.

**My suggestions :**

- **Go step-by-step**

  Do not directly jump to Linux. First try it for a while in a virtual box. After that, if you find it comfortable, try dual-booting Linux. So that if you need windows, you can use it anytime you want. Finally, If you get really comfortable, then remove windows and keep using Linux :)
- Do some research : find out the best Linux distro and best Desktop environment for you.

Comment: Actually a lot of games available for Windows run on Linux too even if it's still a minority. Most notably AAA titles are seldom available on Linux. Some are ported years later, some can run through Wine after a year or so of bug fixing and hardware performance improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is different from Windows.

The desktop version is pretty basic and doesn't take up a lot of resources to run. You can style it how you would like because its pretty much open source. A simple google search can bring up pages of themes.

As a quick search I found this page: [Ubuntu Themes from OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/category/themes-2)

Ubuntu runs off of EXT4 file system, and can read NTFS as well as FAT32. Any file device (as long as it is not corrupted) can be readable from Ubuntu. Now if you formated that device in EXT4, Windows won't be able to see it without additional software. I believe Macs can view it just fine. Best to keep flash drives formatted to Fat32.

Data is stored in a Home folder. Click on computer then click on home, there you will see all the users. It's a lot like Windows C:\users. Inside would be documents, downloads, desktop, etc.

Chances are Windows Software won't work. At least not the newer versions unless there is a linux port. You can try using WINE. .exe extensions are not readable or installable on linux without using WINE but again it's iffy.

Ubuntu comes pre-packed with open office software.

All ports and drivers should work no matter the OS. Manufacturers have made drivers for different versions of operating systems. If there isn't a driver then Ubuntu will automatically install a generic driver.

As a typical user, you wouldn't need to use the terminal. Unless you are trying to run a web server or something of that advanced nature. You can install programs easily through the Ubuntu Software Center.

A thing you could do is run a virtual machine of windows inside ubuntu and you can install the programs you need. Some VM software can have the ability to share the system. Like use both Ubuntu and Windows at the same time, same screen, no needing to switch, can view files on both sides easily, and etc.