# installing windows 10 theme on gnome issue

Tags: gnome, themes, windows-10

Tried installing the Windows 10 theme onto Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.1 LTS 64bit and there is an error I receive. I went about this by the question answered here -> "[Is there any Ubuntu 14.04 theme to make it look like Windows 10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656399/is-there-any-ubuntu-14-04-theme-to-make-it-look-like-windows-10?newreg=9b7ad9f6041a4b92a88c3c8a5536200b)"

This is the error:

```
user@user-linux:~$ sudo apt-get install windos-10-themes
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

What does this mean, how did it happen and how do I solve it?

-Regards

UPDATE:
So there is an issue with the sudo apt-get update and I am not sure why.

```
user@user-linux:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu xenial InRelease         
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [457 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [449 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [384 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [379 kB]
Fetched 1,874 kB in 4s (400 kB/s)                        
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

-Regards

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! That answer you followed and linked is for 14.04, ignoring that and assuming that it may still work: Does this error happen when you run, i.e. `sudo apt-get update` ?

Comment: actually yes it does. I just reran it and I guess I missed it before.

Comment: Then run `ps ax | grep apt` this will give you the processes running at the moment, apt related . To end those processes run `kill ID` where ID is the process number. You may find a few, so do it as many times as needed. Notice that there will be an entry for `ps ax | grep apt` that will be regarding the search you are doing right now, you can identify it easily, it's the last one and has some `--color=auto` text on it,  you don't need to kill that process.

Comment: Once you have done that, run again `sudo apt-get update` to see if it works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Run command sudo su and enter the password, after check there will be another updation process is running in background find that process with 'top' command and kill that   'kill pid' and then run apt-get install windos-10-themes or restart your system and then run the same command